# How convert CT Dicom Files to HU(positive values)?

Tags: dicom

I'm working on DICOM `files(CT files)`.I want to use `Rescaleslope` and `Rescaleintercept` for converting my data to HU with relation:

```
X_IMAGE(:,:,path.ImageIndex) = (dicomread(path))*path.RescaleSlope + path.RescaleIntercept;
```

but the values of these fields are 1 and 0,respectively. So no conversion doing and values don't change. why `Rescaleintercept` is not equal to -1024?
thank you

Answer (score 3):

To convert from the normal units found in CT data (a typical data set ranges from 0 to 4000 or so) you have to apply a linear transformation of the data. The equation is:

hu = pixel_value * slope + intercept

[About More Converting CT Data to Hounsfield Units](https://www.idlcoyote.com/fileio_tips/hounsfield.html)

Answer (score 0):

In python using pydicom library I use the script below to convert to HU:

```
import pydicom
dicom = pydicom.dcmread(filepath)
dicom_hu = dicom.pixel_array * dicom.RescaleSlope + dicom.RescaleIntercept
```

Answer (score 0):

pydicom has a data handler function which automatically converts CT to hounsfield units (provided Hounsfield units are given in the dicom metadata lookup table):
pydicom.pixel_data_handlers.util.apply_modality_lut
https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/dev/reference/generated/pydicom.pixel_data_handlers.util.html

A single dicom slice may be converted using the following code:

```
dcm_i = pydicom.dcmread(dcm_slice_filepath)
arr_i = dcm_i.pixel_array
hu_arr_i = pydicom.pixel_data_handlers.util.apply_modality_lut(arr_i, dcm_i)
```